# Using IvoryGoogleMap bundle in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have really simple and lame question (i hope it's simple).

I'm quite new to symfony2 and i'm not sure how to use bundles. I'm trying to use `IvoryGoogleMapBundle` ( https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle ) and i need to say that documentation is really good but i can't understand one thing. I'll write what have i allready done and what i need:

I've uploaded all the bundle files to `src/Ivory/GoogleMapBundle` directory. Added proper lines to `app/autoload.php` and to `app/Autoload.php`(according to documentation).

Now i'm trying to display the most simple map possible and there are a lot of examples in the documentation but i have no idea how to define new Map object in my controller (all the examples presuppose that `$map` variable allready exists and holds this object). Can you just write the most simple controller for me whitch will have this `$map` variable definition ? Do i need to create all those Entity files mentioned in doc ?

If something is unclear, please just tell me, i'll do my best to explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `$map = $this->get('ivory_google_map.map');` in your controller.

[Full list of services you can use](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) (under **List of available services**)

[What are services?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Side note: external bundles should be placed in /vendor/bundles/Organization/BundleName (so /vendor/bundles/Ivory/GoogleMapBundle and not /src/Ivory/GoogleMapBundle )

Comment: great, that's it! Now i know what are those misterious services :) big thanks!

Comment: what do My\Funcking\ApiHelper and My\Funcking\MapHelper means?

Answer (score 1):

or else il your controller is :

```
class DefaultController extends ContainerAware
{
...
}
```

try this:

```
$map = $this->container->get('ivory_google_map.map');
```